# How to keep this layout uniform across screen sizes

Tags: android, layout, screen-resolution, uniform

I would like to make the following layout, see picture below, where the place of the EditText views stay correct positioned w.r.t. the arrows.

The layout below I've made with a RelativeLayout making use of margins, but this doesn't work when someone installs this app on a 540x960 resolution phone like the HTC sensations.

Thanks in advance for your help!

[Valid XHTML http://www.tricky.dds.nl/gui.png](http://www.tricky.dds.nl/gui.png).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a combination of LinearLayout and RelativeLayout. With LinearLayout you can create spaces on the screen that will be exactly alike on all devices. Let your top level container be a LinearLayout. For instance, to create the second row in the image you reffered to, do something like this:

```
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:orientation="horizontal">

<RelativeLayout
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:layout_weight="1">

</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:layout_weight="1">

<TextView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_centerInParent="true">
</TextView>

</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:layout_weight="1">

</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:layout_weight="1">

<TextView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_centerInParent="true">
</TextView>

</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:layout_weight="1">

</RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Hi Emiam, thanks for your answer. I've implemented like you suggested, but there is still one thing which isn't solved by the answer above. I've made a image to compare different resolutions: http://www.tricky.dds.nl/540x960vs480x800.png Here you can see that the background stored in HDPI doesn't match both resolutions. Should I load different background images based on resolution or is this fixable with the layout? Thanks again!

Comment: I understand your problem. What components do you use? Textviews? From my experience this is solveable just with layout, IF you're dealing with imageviews. Are you using both vertical and horizontal linearlayouts? This enables you to create "boxes" where you can place your compontents. Also make sure to use "android:weighSum" for all the linearlayout parents.

Comment: I only use EditTexts and Textviews. I use a two LinearLayouts one for  the vertical layout and one for every row. The image is just a background covering the whole background (480x7xx) used at both resolutions hence there both HDPI layouts. Is it better to slice my image and give the blocks slices of these background as background image? Many thanks for you time to help!

Comment: Although it's a dirty hack, yes you could do that. Even better would be too keep the background color and just slice up the lines. Good luck!